# Create & Use Custom Controllers and where clause

Tags: visualforce, soql

Im doing the Create & Use Custom Controllers from trailhead on module visual force basics, I do not know what to do but i have an error in my where clause

```
    //This is my controller

public class NewCaseListController {
    private String tipoCaso = 'New';

    public List<Case> getNewCases(){
        List<Case> lista = Database.query('SELECT Id, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE Status = New');
        return lista;
    }

}
```

And my view

---

```
<apex:page controller="NewCaseListController" >
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:repeat value="{! newcases}" var="case" >
            <ul>
                <apex:outputLink value="/{! case.Id }" ><li>{! case.Id }</li></apex:outputLink>
                <li>{! case.CaseNumber }</li>
            </ul>

        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

when preview, says:

expecting a colon, found 'New' 
An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.

Comment: This is my view 
<apex:page controller="NewCaseListController" >
    <apex:pageBlock>
     <apex:repeat value="{! newcases}" var="case" >
            <ul>
                <apex:outputLink value="/{! case.Id }" ><li>{! case.Id }</li></apex:outputLink>
                <li>{! case.CaseNumber }</li>
            </ul>
        
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    
</apex:page>

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! I took a moment to format your code for you. You can do this yourself in the future by using Ctrl-K or Cmd-K after highlighting your code.

Comment: Ctrl-K -> I did not know that. Kudos

Answer (score 3):

Your SOQL is not properly formatted, the status "new" should be in between quotes

```
SELECT Id, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE Status = 'New'
```

you can always check your soql in your developer console to validate it. you will notice that if you paste your original soql and try it out

```
SELECT Id, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE Status = New
```

you will get an

> 'Unknown error parsing query'

Answer (score -2):

```
public with sharing class NewCaseListController {

    public List<Case> getNewCases() {

       string status = 'New';    
        List<Case> results = Database.query(
            'SELECT Id, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE Status = :status '
        );
        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use an Apex bind here. Please do make sure to include some description or explanation in your answers - a code dump is generally not very education to the asker or other community members.